# App with BroadcastReceiver crashes when triggered on boot

Tags: android, kotlin, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to start a service in my app when the phone on which the app is running, boots. I've added a broadcastreceiver, added an intent-filter in the manifest, created a service and added that to the manifest as well. But whenever I boot my phone, after a while it displays that my app has crashed.

An important thing to note is that the service works if it started from MainActivity.

I've seen more questions about this on Stackoverflow, but none of these solve my problem because most of them were of people who forgot to add the receiver to the manifest or something else. 
But I don't know how to read logcat-output as well, from when a phone starts, so I can't determine what's crashing the app.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="nl.arnovanliere.nuntia">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsPictureInPicture="false"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.BroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <service
            android:name=".services.CheckMessagesService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="false" />

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBhlLDqLSihI41pIs-ELuomRWUv6513CeE" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**BroadcastReceiver.kt**

```
class BroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        context?.startService(Intent(context, CheckMessagesService::class.java))
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive BroadcastReceiver called")
    }
}
```

**CheckMessagesService**

```
class CheckMessagesService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate of service called")
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand of service called")
        val runnable = Runnable {
            checkMessages()
            // Only need to check for messages every minute
            Thread.sleep(60000)
        }

        // New thread for checking messages, otherwise the UI-thread would be blocked
        val thread = Thread(runnable)
        thread.start()

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy of service called")
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

checkMessages() is just a function that calls an API and deserializes it to check if a notification has to be send.

I hope one of you can help me.

Comment: First comment out your startService.See if the crash is gone.So then the error is in your service.Write to a txt file instead of using logs.See how far the app went through the txt file.I suppose checkMessages() is causing the error so for start comment that out if everything went good then post that method so we can find the error or you find it yourself.

Comment: Apps don't crash out of nowhere - always include relevant stacktrace. If you're trying to run this on android Oreo or higher issue is quite simple, You just need to use foreground service because starting background service while your app is not in foreground is not allowed.

Comment: thanks @Pawel, startForegroundService did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future viewers: The problem was that I had to use startForegroundService() instead of startService() because I was running it on Android Oreo.

Thanks @Pawel